# Polymer 2 app: paper-button has no text

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, material-design, web-component

**I am very very new to Polymer, Material and Web Components**

I used Polymer CLI to create a polymer 2 application

```
polymer init
```

And then I chose **polymer-2-starter-kit**

I tried to add some [paper buttons](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-button/paper-button) to my view1 file, but I found out that paper-button has not added to the bower dependencies, so I added it myself. My bower.json looks like this:

```html
    {
  "name": "my-app",
  "authors": [
    "Ehsun"
  ],
  "license": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "app-layout": "PolymerElements/app-layout#2.0-preview",
    "app-route": "PolymerElements/app-route#2.0-preview",
    "iron-flex-layout": "PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout#2.0-preview",
    "iron-icon": "PolymerElements/iron-icon#2.0-preview",
    "iron-iconset-svg": "PolymerElements/iron-iconset-svg#2.0-preview",
    "iron-localstorage": "PolymerElements/iron-localstorage#2.0-preview",
    "iron-media-query": "PolymerElements/iron-media-query#2.0-preview",
    "iron-pages": "PolymerElements/iron-pages#2.0-preview",
    "iron-selector": "PolymerElements/iron-selector#2.0-preview",
    "paper-icon-button": "PolymerElements/paper-icon-button#2.0-preview",
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "webcomponentsjs": "webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#^1.0.0-rc.1",
    "paper-button": "PolymerElements/paper-button#1.0.14"
        
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "web-component-tester": "6.0.0-prerelease.5"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

and I added the markup to one of my views as this:

```html
    <!--
@license
Copyright (c) 2016 The Polymer Project Authors. All rights reserved.
This code may only be used under the BSD style license found at http://polymer.github.io/LICENSE.txt
The complete set of authors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/AUTHORS.txt
The complete set of contributors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/CONTRIBUTORS.txt
Code distributed by Google as part of the polymer project is also
subject to an additional IP rights grant found at http://polymer.github.io/PATENTS.txt
-->

<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
s<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-styles/paper-styles.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">



<dom-module id="my-view1">
    <template>
        <style include="shared-styles">
            :host {
                display: block;

                padding: 10px;
            }
        </style>

        <div class="card pink" >
            <h1>Start Now</h1>
            <a href="/view2"><paper-button raised class="indigo">go</paper-button></a>
        </div>


        <paper-button class="pink">link</paper-button>
        <paper-button raised class="indigo">raised</paper-button>
        <paper-button toggles raised class="green">toggles</paper-button>
        <paper-button disabled class="disabled">disabled</paper-button>
    </template>


    <script>
        class MyView1 extends Polymer.Element {
            static get is() {
                return 'my-view1';
            }
        }

        window.customElements.define(MyView1.is, MyView1);
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Now the buttons are text-less as this:

[image]

Comment: You should try with `2.0-preview` branch of `paper-button`. See [this](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/about_20#elements) doc.

Comment: Thanks. It works now. This is the solution. Would be nice if you posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see that you are using `1.0.14` tag of `paper-button`. That should not be compatible with `v2.x` of Polymer as polymer V2.x is on v1 spec of web-components and `paper-button v1.x` on v0.

The specific reason why your text is not coming up should be deprecation of `content` tag in favour of `slot` tag in v1 spec.

You should try `2.0-preview` branch/tag of `paper-button`.